# How to get counts of Edges related to a node in one query - NEO4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two questions.

What is the best way to index user activities like posts, reposts, comments, upvotes, and downvotes. My current solution is representing every activity as a POST. It should work, but I know its quite expensive to regard upvotes and downvotes as new nodes when I can just use a relationship to represent this. But then, I want to be able to fetch everything once and order.

Secondly: When I run the following excluding the `WITH` and following `MATCH`, The result is larger but as I try to get the counts of reposts, replies and upvotes. The result keeps getting smaller and eventually nothing.

```
MATCH (me:User {id: "172ed572-e3af-d3ee-77c0-8d9d181b12f1"})-[:COLLEAGUE_OF]-(u:User)-[posted:POSTED]->(p:Post) WHERE posted.date >= 0
WITH p, posted, u AS user MATCH (p)-[ro:REPOST_OF]-(:Post)
WITH count(ro) AS reposts, posted, ro, user MATCH (p)-[rt:REPLY_TO]->(:Post)
WITH count(rt) AS replies, posted, user, reposts MATCH (p)-[uv:UP_VOTE]->(:Post)
WITH count(uv) AS upvotes, posted, user, reposts, replies, p
RETURN p AS post,  posted, user, reposts, replies
ORDER BY -posted.date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to read the documentation on [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) (like `COUNT`). In particular, you need to understand that the `WITH` (and `RETURN`) clause treats terms that *do not* contain aggregating functions as the "grouping keys" for the terms that *do* contain aggregating functions.

   For example, a clause such as `WITH foo, COUNT(foo) AS fooCount` will *always* produce a `fooCount` of 1.
2. `WITH` clauses *must* specify the bound variables whose values you want to use later in the same query; any unspecified variables will be dropped. SInce your second and third `WITH` clauses do not specify `p`, their subsequent `MATCH` clauses are actually NOT using the previously bound value for `p` (but creating totally new `p` variables, each having multiple values).
3. You should use `OPTIONAL MATCH` instead of `MATCH` to get the counts of things that may not exist. A `MATCH` would cause the entire query to abort if it fails to find a match.
4. You neglected to make the `(p)-[ro:REPOST_OF]-(:Post)` relationship pattern *directional*. If you wanted to get a count of the number of times that `p` was reposted, so you should have used the pattern `(p)<-[ro:REPOST_OF]-(:Post)`.
5. You forgot to return `upvotes`.
6. You should use `ORDER BY posted.date DESC` instead of `ORDER BY -posted.date`.

This may work better for you:

```
MATCH (:User {id: "172ed572-e3af-d3ee-77c0-8d9d181b12f1"})-[:COLLEAGUE_OF]-(user:User)-[posted:POSTED]->(p:Post)
WHERE posted.date >= 0
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[ro:REPOST_OF]-(:Post)
WITH p, posted, user, COUNT(ro) AS reposts
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[rt:REPLY_TO]->(:Post)
WITH p, posted, user, reposts, COUNT(rt) AS replies
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[uv:UP_VOTE]->(:Post)
RETURN p, posted, user, reposts, replies, COUNT(uv) AS upvotes
ORDER BY posted.date DESC
```